# pgpoolAdmin could not be able to proceed after step 2

Tags: postgresql, pgpool

I am currently configuring Postgres pgPoolAdmin.

[image: The errorn screenshot attached.].

How I can correct?

Comment: Hey, Is it solved? I'm facing the same issue too. Kindly update your solution @Titus Rakkesh

Answer (score 0):

.pcppass file is missing from the specified directory. You will need to create the file (contains user and password) according to this link, http://www.pgpool.net/docs/latest/pgpool-en.html#pcp_comand_password Make sure the .pcppass file has permission 0600. You may also need to change its owner/group to apache/www-data user depending on your system.